# Potential Moderator Election 2022

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

We're contemplating a moderator election before the year ends to increase the number of mods to five. I'd just like to have an idea of community interest in this (since obviously we'll look a bit silly if no-one applies for the job).

So if you have time just put a like on either of the answers below.

Comment: What are the requirements to become a mod?

Comment: For additional info, refer to [past elections](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election), [What's it like being a Workplace Moderator?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5938), and the [Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/). Also: [Current moderators: please tell us about the job](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2476) and [What are the day-to-day activities of Moderators?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6553)

Comment: @zmike The election process including moderator requirements is described in detail here: [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360). Details on the candidate score can be found here: [What are the details on the "candidate score" which shows during an election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252641). A high candidate score isn't a hard requirement but tends to be important. Historically people with (very) low scores haven't had great odds at attracting votes.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's a terrible idea, no one has time for that. What were you thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's an excellent idea! Exactly what we need and I'm ready to self nominate for the position(s).

Comment: If the mods need help, I think it's an excellent idea to elect more. But I'm not going to self-nominate, so I guess I can't upvote this answer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere thats fine, although I do think you'd make an excellent mod. At this point we're just trying to gauge interest. If enough people are interested there will be two slots available rather than one. If there's not enough interest, we'll just defer it until next year.

Comment: I agree with @JoeStrazzere but I can't upvote the answer because I am not going to self nominate.

Comment: I wont self-nominate either, and I can't upvote.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter you'd make a good mod imo

Comment: @Kilisi I'm a mod at another site now, stepping into a new role at my job, and have family matters that are rather pressing.  In the future, I might consider it.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter up to you, you're an extremely valuable member of TWP with or without a diamond.