# How to properly review this answer

Tags: discussion

I was tasked with reviewing [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/94915/66895) in the low quality queue. I am new to this queue, so I am uncertain how it should be reviewed.

IMO this clearly isn't the right answer, but at the same time, there is nothing wrong with the answer itself. The user explain their opinion in a clear concise manner and it sounds like this their real opinion of how OP should handle the situation.

Should this be reviewed as "Look OK" and let OP decide which answer they accept, or should the answer be "Recommend Deletion" because the answer is not correct action OP should take. I also don't think it will help users in the future who are in a similar situation.

Comment: Related: [Are we using NAA and VLQ flags correctly?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/are-we-using-naa-and-vlq-flags-correctly) and [Bad answers being marked as low quality, when they aren't](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4463/bad-answers-being-marked-as-low-quality-when-they-arent). There might be more or a more recent consensus but the search isn't being very cooperative.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same question recently, and @Lilienthal's answer on the second link answers it pretty well for me.

Comment: The correctness of an answer is determined by the voting system. You should not judge the correctness by recommending to delete, you could be wrong

Comment: I agree with @PlasmaHH.   This community will typically downvote or flag inappropriate "Point Grab" type questions.

Comment: Thanks, I wanna learn how to do these things right so I can be a productive member of the community

Comment: @SaggingRufus And we very much appreciate that! One of the best places to start, if you haven't found it already, is the [Privileges page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) of your profile. There should be a brief introduction and how-to for every new privilege you can get.

Comment: @SaggingRufus I thought you were just supposed to click randomly when you get new privileges to learn how they work. _enderland is doing it wrong_ ;-)